# CTE and joining 2 lookup tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I have two CTE queries, which I've simplified, and a select statement below hoping to join 2 lookup tables:

```
with salesCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from sales
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
),
paymentsCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from payments
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
)
select 
    il.itemCode as itemCode,
    il.itemName as itemName,
    cl.customerCode as customerCode,
    cl.customerName as customerName,
    sal.quantity as quantitySold,
    pay.quantity as quantityPaid,
    sal.quantity - pay.quantity as quantityBalance
from
--This is where I'm having issues
```

So I've tried various from clauses, but I'm either not getting a result set or it's only a very small portion of the expected results.

The most logical one I've though of to try wasn't working (no response):

```
from items il
join salesCTE sal on il.itemCode = sal.itemCode
join paymentsCTE pay on il.itemCode = pay.itemCode
join customers cl on (cl.customerCode = sal.custCode OR cl.customerCode = pay.custCode)
where 0=0
```

I also tried:

```
from items il, customers cl, salesCTE sal, paymentsCTE pay
where 0=0
and (il.itemCode = sal.itemCode OR il.itemCode = pay.itemCode)
and (cl.customerCode = sal.custCode OR il.itemCode = pay.custCode)
```

Am I trying to do too many things with this query?

I've also set up a SQL Fiddle with some dummy data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4de7b/7

Below is the expected results for customerCode = '102'

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ ItemCode ║   ItemName   ║ CustomerCode ║ CustomerName ║ Sold ║ Paid ║ Balance ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════╬══════╬═════════╣
║      903 ║ Cowl         ║          102 ║ Clark Kent   ║    0 ║    1 ║      -1 ║
║      900 ║ Web Shooters ║          102 ║ Clark Kent   ║    0 ║    3 ║      -3 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

The idea is that if there is a record inserted into the sales table, for ItemCode 900, Sold would be 1 and balance would be -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with salesCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from sales
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
),
paymentsCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from payments
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
)
select 
    il.itemCode as itemCode,
    il.itemName as itemName,
    cl.customerCode as customerCode,
    cl.customerName as customerName,
    sal.quantity as quantitySold,
    pay.quantity as quantityPaid,
    sal.quantity - pay.quantity as quantityBalance
from salesCTE sal 
     full outer join paymentsCTE pay on (sal.itemCode = pay.itemCode)
     join items il on nvl(sal.itemCode, pay.itemCode) = il.itemCode 
     join customers cl on (case when pay.itemCode is null then sal.custCode else pay.custCode end) = cl.customerCode;
```

As I understand you want to get the information about payments and sales of your items.

In this case you need a full join of sales and payments in order to retrieve all the itemcodes.

Then you just join with customers and items to get some additional info (you need to join either by columns from payments or sales).

P.S. There is a strange thing with your fiddle data - sales contain itemcodes that are not in items table. If it's the case you can use LEFT JOIN items instead of JOIN items (but it's really strange)

**Update**: I think you just mixed up column values when inserted into sales in the fiddle

The other option - if you need to get the information both for each item and customer.

In this case you need full join both by itemcode and custCode:

```
with salesCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from sales
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
),
paymentsCTE (itemCode, custCode, quantity) as (
    select
        itemCode as itemCode,
        customerCode as custCode,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from payments
    group by itemCode, customerCode
    order by 1
)
select 
    il.itemCode as itemCode,
    il.itemName as itemName,
    cl.customerCode as customerCode,
    cl.customerName as customerName,
    nvl(sal.quantity, 0) as quantitySold,
    nvl(pay.quantity, 0) as quantityPaid,
    nvl(sal.quantity, 0) - nvl(pay.quantity, 0) as quantityBalance
from salesCTE sal 
     full outer join paymentsCTE pay on (sal.itemCode = pay.itemCode 
                                         and sal.custCode = pay.custCode)
     join items il on nvl(sal.itemCode, pay.itemCode) = il.itemCode 
     join customers cl on nvl(sal.custCode, pay.custCode) = cl.customerCode;
```

Comment: I randomized data, I went back and filled it with a more logical set.  I'm looking through the result, and though it looks formed, there seems to be some inconsistencies.  But that went a lot further than I had, I'll work off what you have so far.

Comment: @Chester Yes, there was a problem with joining customers. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Chester Also there can be a problem if there are rows in sales and payments with the same itemcode but different customers. If it's the case then you need to join customers twice

Comment: @Chester I've added another query which will solve the problem with different customers for the same item. But it would be better if you could explain more precisely what are you looking for

Comment: I've edited the question to sort of show the expected report values, with just a subset of the data. Hope that enlightens. I'm checking out your edit now, also. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it and am learning so much from this.

Comment: @Chester The second query in my answer should give the correct result then (I've added NVL to convert nulls to zeros).

Comment: Cool!  That did it. Now the fun part of understanding how it works and applying it to my particular problem. I've also edited the original question / expected return table to accurately display the expected results.